# Image is not responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

We re trying to customize an element on my WordPress website but it's impossible.

I'm trying to paste it into custom CSS into my WordPress website because the image is not responsive for mobile but it's not working.

**from**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img {
    width: auto;
}
```

**TO**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img {
width: 500px;`
}
```

Comment: In your code there are two `{}` brackets missing, it needs to be `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img { width: 500px; } }`

Comment: Looks like a typo but also, there is nothing on kirmanidis.gr related to your question...

Comment: Please see [ask]. You'd need to include some HTML in your post for us to help. Put it and your CSS in a demo snippet using the editor. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){.et_pb_image_0 .et_pb_image_wrap img {width: 500px;}}

Correction